Azure DevOps is not gathering all changes when using schduled cron trigger
We are using Azure DevOps YAML pipeline with a schedule cron trigger in order to build and release our app daily in our test environment (YAML content below). However, it seems that when the build starts, only the latest commit show in the build changes. How can I make sure that all commits between the previous build and the current one shows up in the changes ?
I have to mention that, in one of the stages, there is a job with continueOnError set to true. Maybe this could be the cause too ?
YAML content:

# Pipeline build name
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)

schedules:
  - cron: '0 11 * * 1-5' # This value use UTC, so we need to set it at 11am for it to run at 1pm in french time zone
    displayName: Livraison automatique en recette
    always: true # Whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run; the default is false.
    batch: false # Whether to run the pipeline if the previously scheduled run is in-progress; the default is false.
    branches:
      include:
        - develop

trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: github
    ref: refs/heads/develop

# Build input parameters
parameters:
  ...


# Build variable
# For now, values are the same as previous pipelines
variables:
  ...

# Build stages, depending on input parameters
stages:
  ...

I've tried setting the always and batch parameters to true, then to false. I've also tried triggering the pipeline manually, in which case all changes appear correctly.

You have disabled the Continuous integration (CI) trigger by setting trigger: none. Is the pipeline supposed to run only with the CRON schedule trigger?

The pipeline is supposed to run either with the CRON schedule trigger, or manually

On pipeline result page, there's a "view change(s)" button, it shows the commits and associated changes that triggered the build.
It compares with last successful run:

If no change from last successful run, in new run the button will not display.
If new changes from last successful run, in new run the button will include the new changes.
But if last pipeline run does not succeed, in new run the previous changes will be still included in the button.

With continueOnError: true, the step will proceed to next one, if real error reported in the step, the pipeline is treated as not successful, the old changes will still be contained as below:

The always and batch only determine how the schedule trigger works, please check the doc for the usage.
In above, the changes could be different based on previous run state.
If you would like to get all commits between the previous build and the current one(current repo, not repository resource), you can use rest api Builds - Get Changes Between Builds.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/changes?fromBuildId={fromBuildId}&$top={$top}&api-version=7.1


BTW, the github repository resource in your yaml is not correct, please don't use self as the name as it points to current repo, change it to others. please refer to the sample for your reference.
Check with source repo on github, the commits are same for the two triggers.


Thank you for your response. The thing I don't understand is why all changes doesn't show when pipeline is triggered automatically, but appears correctly when triggered manually. Did I missed something ?
BTW, thanks for the github repository resource name. I will change it

Does it checkout same branch(ref) between schedule trigger and manual trigger on your pipeline? You can confirm on the pipeline run result page. In addition, which changes are not displayed? the changes from repository resource, or the changes from current repo? Please also check the previous pipeline state if it's not succeeded as mentioned above.

Yes it does.
Let's say, between monday's run and yesterday's run, there was 5 commits merged into develop, which is the main branch of the github repository. When schedule trigger starts, in the current build changes, I can only see the latest commit that was merged onto develop.
The previous pipeline state was "Succeeded with issues", since the task with "continue on error" was executed but failed

"Succeeded with issues" are treated as "not successful", the changes in previous run will appear in current run. Please also check changes in previous run. With same scenario, it will contain old changes and new changes in current run on my side, which is correct behavior. Can you check if you have 5 commits on github develop branch? In case you merged them together as one commit, you can do the change from website with several times to have 5 commits.

The manual trigger and schedule trigger pipeline have same changes on my side. If possible, can you share a minimum reproducible yaml for further checking?

I checked if there was really 5 commits on github between the 2 runs, and they actually are. Plus, they were not merged as one commit. I will try to provide you a minimum reproductible yaml ASAP

Thank you @AlexisJACOB. BTW, is your source repo(yaml) in devops git or github git? Will try to check following your scenario.

The source repo is on github

So you have two develop github branches in yaml, one is from source repo, the other is from github repository resource. Tried to merge from both source repo and repository resource repo, all commits can show fine on both schedule trigger and manual trigger, I will add the appearance in reply above, please have a check. You can try to create a new pipeline with same yaml for a check.  Will wait your minimum reproducible yaml and check further, thanks.

@AlexisJACOB, may i know how is it going? Does it work on the new pipeline? You can follow the points above to double check the setting. Please let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Hi, sorry for the late response. It looks like changing the resource repository as you suggested (by changing the name, and adding the endpoint) resolved the issue. I'm going to mark your answer as the solution. Thanks again !
